# Sending Json String using Apache Http Client within same tomcat server

Tags: java, json, tomcat, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to send json to server using apache http client.I have tried creating the json string using both Gson and jackson APIs,I am getting the valid json String using both ways,but the problem i am facing is when sending json with apache http client, i am getting bad request.Is it the problem that json string getting converted to something like invalid json which i can see on the console or it could be other issue.here is my code

```
objAuthRequest.setModality(objFITransXTRequest.getModality());
        objAuthRequest.setUidNumber(objFITransXTRequest.getUidNumber());
        objAuthRequest.setRrn("123456789133");
        objAuthRequest.setStan("12345600");
        objAuthRequest.setPid(objFITransXTRequest.getPid());
        objAuthRequest.setHmac(objFITransXTRequest.getHmac());
        objAuthRequest.setCi(objFITransXTRequest.getCi());
        objAuthRequest.setsKey(objFITransXTRequest.getsKey());
        objAuthRequest.setMetaData(objFITransXTRequest.getMetaData());

        try {

           Gson objGson = new Gson();
            String strRequestJson = objGson.toJson(objAuthRequest);
            System.out.println("Request json " + strRequestJson);

            response = objMWTHttpClient.execute(strRequestJson, URL);
            System.out.println("Response json " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("## Exception occured :: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
```

Here is my apache client code

```
public String execute(String authenticateData, String srtULR) throws ParseException, Exception {
        String resoutput = "";
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            //HttpPut reqFundTransf = new HttpPut(srtULR);
            HttpPost reqFundTransf = new HttpPost(srtULR);

            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(authenticateData);
            reqFundTransf.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            reqFundTransf.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(reqFundTransf);
            HttpEntity respEntity = resp.getEntity();
            if (respEntity != null) {
                resoutput = EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return resoutput;
}
```

On Console, i am getting these messages

```
Request json {"modality":{"fp":true,"otp":false},"uidNumber":"49664043668","rrn":"123456789133","stan":"12345600","pid":"YUVIL7CKWbBjFV+UCZBKGMnLJeHSNJjrZ6r+0kyfMZl0VEKNeIHyeaXFPLsYXyxJ9qISBTPmN/4qrS82AT781Q\u003d\u003d","hmac":"XuVPiZ9kLxHSAzxzyFqu+eY18F1bQVqOzjbGF7Pc21L2ohIFM+Y3/iqtLzYBPvzV","ci":"20170227","sKey":"lrq66RF9C0H00tFVA3MjRRui0NFyM/1BlYxfJkzHFZhrWaLt1xpUd7M1z1skeXqJwNmB7Ygcyht22Tqr701eHSiZTKWl6N4gJLDr4EZjDB+OYqDTg28qSiHC3/TDvASr9m+F0ymKZhAdw7aASf+ZCxpkdjBOI/FzaIlTo67r9azYeVKPd/53bnpOvboxUdpt0coI8ElheTArcE5xQVDVC3Y5iJYkARjVgRonrjWSLlb0D9WzZ2Aolq2vnwo7nnglb0uqiqanUUrStqK//MNcVq5R5acu5hZv83XZNH0m/4v1+Ku3zQp0Kuc6nRNkE0M6f+LKZJ8JlkeSnIwoubFA1Q\u003d\u003d","metaData":{"udc":"AX20123","pip":"10.230.23.24","lot":"P","lov":"244221"}}
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:122 - CookieSpec selected: best-match
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:75 - Auth cache not set in the context
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:219 - Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:250 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG MainClientExec:217 - Opening connection {}->http://localhost:8080
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG HttpClientConnectionOperator:120 - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG HttpClientConnectionOperator:127 - Connection established 127.0.0.1:46299<->127.0.0.1:8080
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG MainClientExec:238 - Executing request POST /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG MainClientExec:243 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG MainClientExec:249 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 737
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:8080
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 737[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:86 - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"modality":{"fp":true,"otp":false},"uidNumber":"49664043668","rrn":"123456789133","stan":"12345600","pid":"YUVIL7CKWbBjFV+UCZBKGMnLJeHSNJjrZ6r+0kyfMZl0VEKNeIHyeaXFPLsYXyxJ9qISBTPmN/4qrS82AT781Q\u003d\u003d","hmac":"XuVPiZ9kLxHSAzxzyFqu+eY18F1bQVqOzjbGF7Pc21L2ohIFM+Y3/iqtLzYBPvzV","ci":"20170227","sKey":"lrq66RF9C0H00tFVA3MjRRui0NFyM/1BlYxfJkzHFZhrWaLt1xpUd7M1z1skeXqJwNmB7Ygcyht22Tqr701eHSiZTKWl6N4gJLDr4EZjDB+OYqDTg28qSiHC3/TDvASr9m+F0ymKZhAdw7aASf+ZCxpkdjBOI/FzaIlTo67r9azYeVKPd/53bnpOvboxUdpt0coI8ElheTArcE5xQVDVC3Y5iJYkARjVgRonrjWSLlb0D9WzZ2Aolq2vnwo7nnglb0uqiqanUUrStqK//MNcVq5R5acu5hZv83XZNH0m/4v1+Ku3zQp0Kuc6nRNkE0M6f+LKZJ8JlkeSnIwoubFA1Q\u003d\u003d","metaData":{"udc":"AX20123","pip":"10.230.23.24","lot":"P","lov":"244221"}}"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2017 07:41:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:113 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2017 07:41:20 GMT
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: close
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:87 - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG MainClientExec:126 - Connection discarded
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:79 - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2017-02-23 13:11:20 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:286 - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
```

I am printing the generated json string on console "Request Json {}".it is valid ,but after few lines,the json is sent something like this

```
 http-outgoing-0 >> "{"modality":{"fp":true,"otp":false},"uidNumber":"49664043668","rrn":"123456789133","stan":"12345600","pid":"YUVIL7CKWbBjFV+UCZBKGMnLJeHSNJjrZ6r+0kyfMZl0VEKNeIHyeaXFPLsYXyxJ9qISBTPmN/4qrS82AT781Q\u003d\u003d","hmac":"XuVPiZ9kLxHSAzxzyFqu+eY18F1bQVqOzjbGF7Pc21L2ohIFM+Y3/iqtLzYBPvzV","ci":"20170227","sKey":"lrq66RF9C0H00tFVA3MjRRui0NFyM/1BlYxfJkzHFZhrWaLt1xpUd7M1z1skeXqJwNmB7Ygcyht22Tqr701eHSiZTKWl6N4gJLDr4EZjDB+OYqDTg28qSiHC3/TDvASr9m+F0ymKZhAdw7aASf+ZCxpkdjBOI/FzaIlTo67r9azYeVKPd/53bnpOvboxUdpt0coI8ElheTArcE5xQVDVC3Y5iJYkARjVgRonrjWSLlb0D9WzZ2Aolq2vnwo7nnglb0uqiqanUUrStqK//MNcVq5R5acu5hZv83XZNH0m/4v1+Ku3zQp0Kuc6nRNkE0M6f+LKZJ8JlkeSnIwoubFA1Q\u003d\u003d","metaData":{"udc":"AX20123","pip":"10.230.23.24","lot":"P","lov":"244221"}}"
```

When I tested this out going json string, it is invalid means syntax is incorrect.I have checked each and every field in my java object,everything looks fine.Please guide what to do.Thanks

Edit: I am sending  the request from one project to another within the same server.

Comment: The "Bad Request" is an HTTP error, it means you try a request that is not correct. Are you sure you have to use a POST? (it could be a PUT?) or check the `Content-Type` too, be sure it is `application/json`.

Comment: Yes it is application/json and the method is post

Comment: The json's syntax is correct though. Are you sure the problem is not on the receiving server side ? Can you actually successfully POST that json via a 3rd party http client  (cUrl, postman...)?

Comment: @Jeremy Grand, Thanks for mentioning about postman.now  i am getting 403 status "Access to the specified resource has been forbidden" when I directly hit from postman. How can I solve it?

Comment: Well, you have to investigate why your server restricts access to the resource. It's another matter. I can't magically solve your problems without any info on your application.